# Unable to remove strings containing parentheses

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a list of strings and remove any which contain an open parentheses.

'''

```
counter = 0
for i in self.command_list:
            if i.find("(") != -1:
                self.command_list.pop(counter)
            counter = counter + 1
```

'''

The if statement properly identifies if a string contains an open parentheses so why isn't pop working?

Comment: `[i for i in self.command_list if "(" not in i]` - and very bad idea to mutate a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Related question about why it is a bad idea to remove items from a list that you are iterating over: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
command_list = ["first",
                "fir(st",
                "second",
                "(second)"]

command_list = [i for i in command_list if "(" not in i]
print(command_list)
```

The problem might be that you are looping through the `command_list` and when you pop, indexing changes on-the-fly, so you miss adjacent items.

If you don't need to store popped items you can re-write the list as above.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, initialisation of `counter` is missing.

After the first `pop()`, the list was already changed, so your `counter` is wrong by `1`. This gets worse by each `pop()` you do.

You get an excellent link and a suggestion in the comments.
The comments say, it is bad idea to change a list when you are iterating over it. Using pop many times is not efficient. If you insist on that, I would be updating `counter` only in the `else:` part of the `if` statement. There is also a suggestion going through the list backwards.

Better is to use the construct from the comment:

`[  i   for   i in self.command_list    if "(" not in i   ]`